# Возможно ли удаление из AVL дерева с инвалидацией только удаленного элемента

Tags: c++, алгоритм, дерево

Я храню итераторы на элементы AVL дерева, при удалении элемента из него некоторые итераторы могут указывать на другие элементы то есть инвалидироваться. Возможно ли удаление из дерева только с инвалидацией удаленного элемента? Если возможно прошу поделиться идеей, реализаций. Все реализации которые нашел в интернете делают копию из одного узла в другой во время удаления. В красно черном дереве STL по стандарту инвалидируется только удаленный элемент.

Comment: Конечно, возможно. Узлы не перемещаются в памяти. При удалении обновляются только указатели и счетчики (правда, возможно, во многих элементах, а не только у соседей удаленного).

Comment: @Chorkov да именно так и нужно, а то все что нашел данные по узлам гоняют а не указатели меняют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация из boost при удалении инвалидирует только удаляемые элементы:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/avltree.html#idm23580-bb